# How exactly to use updateDimensionProperties in google-spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-sheets

I tried to add columns in my Google Sheet, using [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) lib.

But I always get error: `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: doc.updateDimensionProperties is not a function`

Here is my code:

```
const doc = new GoogleSpreadsheet('google-id');

async function updateTable(token){
  await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require('./credentials.json'));
  await doc.updateDimensionProperties("COLUMNS", 5, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal and your situation as follows.

- You want to use `updateDimensionProperties()` using [google-spreadsheet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet).
- You have already been able to get and put values using Sheets API.
- You are using the latest version of google-spreadsheet.

#### Modification points:

- When I saw the script of "node-google-spreadsheet", it seems that `updateDimensionProperties()` is required to be used for `sheet` object. [Ref](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/301dfa9fb128c7bb28ab13e40005823c23cd55bf/lib/GoogleSpreadsheetWorksheet.js#L483)
- And also, it seems that the arguments of `updateDimensionProperties()` are `columnsOrRows`, `props`, `bounds`, `bounds.startIndex` and `bounds.endIndex`.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

From:

```
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require('./credentials.json'));
await doc.updateDimensionProperties("COLUMNS", 5, 1);
```

To:

```
await doc.useServiceAccountAuth(require('./credentials.json'));
await doc.loadInfo();
const sheet = doc.sheetsByIndex[0];
await sheet.updateDimensionProperties("COLUMNS", { pixelSize: 200 }, { startIndex: 2, endIndex: 3 });
```

- In this modified script, as the sample, the width of the column "C" of the 1st sheet in the Spreadsheet is changed to 200 pixels.

#### References:

- [updateDimensionProperties of document of node-google-spreadsheet](https://github.com/theoephraim/node-google-spreadsheet/blob/95c3271b250bf4f9d99651a8269d1f76719e2168/docs/classes/google-spreadsheet-worksheet.md#updatedimensionpropertiescolumnsorrows-props-bounds-async-idfn-updatedimensionproperties)
- [DimensionProperties](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#DimensionProperties)

  - It seems that this object is used as `props` of `updateDimensionProperties()`.